# Add condition group in Views filter handler

Tags: views

I have a Views filter handler, which does

```
$this->query->add_where(
  $this->options['group'],
  $this->real_field,
  vms_get_current_mlid(),
  $this->operator = ($this->operator == '=') ? 'IN' : 'NOT IN'
);
```

Which initially looks fine, but fails with "NOT IN", when the field value is NULL, as `NOT IN (100)` does not return TRUE for a NULL value, which is what I would like.

When the operator is 'NOT IN', I need to add a "OR IS NULL" operator as well, but still keep it within the same group.

If the filters are

> Node is "page" AND NID_REFERENCE NOT IN (100, 101, 102)

I would like that to become

> Node is "page" AND (NID_REFERENCE NOT IN (100, 101, 102) OR NID_REFERENCE IS NOT NULL)

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The answer turns out to be that  [`add_where()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/plugins!views_plugin_query_default.inc/function/views_plugin_query_default%3A%3Aadd_where/7) also accepts a [`DatabaseCondition`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!query.inc/class/DatabaseCondition/7) argument, meaning I could do

```
$this->query->add_where(
  $group,
  db_or()
    ->condition($table, $vms_target, 'NOT IN')
    ->condition($table, $vms_target, 'IS NULL')
)
```

Comment: Doh! Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't quite wrap my head around those queries in your last comment, but instead I tried exploring how Views does between operations. Check out [`db_or()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_or/7) which is used by [views_handler_filter_numeric::op_between()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/handlers%21views_handler_filter_numeric.inc/function/views_handler_filter_numeric%3A%3Aop_between/7) - I think that will do it.

Comment: I tested this, and the problem is that the filter is moved to a _new_ group, which means the View will no longer respect the filter group settings. Somehow the existing group needs a _sub_ group, for this to work.

Comment: @Letharion I'm not sure what you mean by _the filter group settings_? Isn't the only group setting the operator (ie _AND_ or _OR_)? I think I'm missing something :)

Comment: My bad. If the View has, set in the UI, two groups of filters, like `(node.type = 'page' AND nid_ref NOT IN (100, 101)) AND (nid_ref IN (102))`, your suggestion turns this into `(node.type = 'page') AND (nid_ref IN (102)) AND/OR (nid_ref NOT IN (100, 101))` as opposed to `(node.type = 'page' AND (nid_ref NOT IN (100, 101) OR nid_ref IS NOT NULL)) AND (nid_ref IN (102))` because you add a $new_group, instead of manipulating the existing one.

Comment: Hehe, yeah, the queries got kinda long :P Suffice it to say that the parenthesis moved around in a way that broke the query. :)